# Expected expression in conditional in let statement

Tags: swift, xcode, conditional-statements

I am getting this error on the after the let statement. Does anyone know why I am getting this error?

```
@objc private func didtaploginbutton() {
    passwordTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    usernameTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    
guard let usernameEmail = usernameTextField.text, !usernameEmail.isEmpty,
    let password = passwordTextField.text, !password.isEmpty, password.count >= 8, else do {
            
            return
          }
            
    }
```

Comment: you should write the error and explain better the situation and the an overview of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `do`. It's usually only used when you want to handle an error with a [Do-Catch](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ErrorHandling.html#ID541) block. You might also want to break the expression into multiple lines, so that it's easier to read.

Also, you have an extra comma (`,`) before the `else`. You need to remove this.

```
guard
    let usernameEmail = usernameTextField.text,
    !usernameEmail.isEmpty,
    let password = passwordTextField.text,
    !password.isEmpty,
    password.count >= 8
else { return }
```

Comment: Xcode is telling me i need the do catch in order for it to work? not sure why its giving me that solution also breaking it up didnt help and its still giving me this message. :/

Comment: @AndrewHughes hmm... can you post code for the entire `didtaploginbutton` function?

Comment: @objc private func didtaploginbutton() {
        passwordTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        usernameTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        
        guard
      let usernameEmail = usernameTextField.text, !usernameEmail.isEmpty,
            let password = passwordTextField.text, !password.isEmpty, password.count >= 8, else do {
                  return
                  
                  }
           
     }

Comment: @AndrewHughes you have an extra `,`. Sorry for not catching that the first time.